# what is considered as good reps?

Tags: discussion

What reputation is considered good for a 14 year old, who is a member of SO for about 4 months?

So, my reputation as of typing this is 3842 Is it good enough?

Comment: Umm... you're good... enough? I don't think we have DataExplorer query for average reputation based on user's age?

Comment: When I was your age, Stack Overflow didn't even **exist**.

Comment: @Andrew T.: I happen to remember minitech writing [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58346/members-by-age-and-reputation) some time ago, and me [revising its result limit](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59755/members-by-age-and-reputation) to include... well, more users. It returns users by age and rep but doesn't calculate averages (not that it would be difficult to tweak it to do so).

Comment: When I was your age the **World Wide Web** did not even exist!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: When you were his age... **I** didn't exist.

Comment: If you answer 1000 times badly, you'd probably get 10000 reputation easily, even though the quality of each isn't the best. The Stack Overflow reputation system tends to favour quantity over quality in their answers, which makes reputation a poor measure of your programming knowledge/ability.

Comment: Note also that the query also shows users where they've just put in the minimum age on sign-up to remain anonymous.

Comment: Damn, I shouldn't have asked that question

Comment: If you evaluate yourself based upon rep, you have bigger issues in life and need to step away from SE and address those issues immediately. This isn't the first time that your rep has been your concern (yesterday in the Tavern, few days prior to that as well and so on...), so please do think about addressing it seriously.

Comment: @InfiniteHappiness *"If you evaluate yourself based on rep"* Yes. I *used to* do that, when I started out here, check the timestamp of this question.. and yes, I remember complaining about downvotes once. The one yesterday, was meant to be helpful to site. An accepted answer had 4 downvotes. I asked if something could be done regarding that. You seem to be thinking too deep. Chill out.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use reputation as a metric to measure your overall value as a SO Programmer.

It's meant to be a tool for others to judge how knowledgeable you are- not as a tool for you to judge yourself.

When you only look at your own reputation, you throw away all of the other things that make you a good programmer. We don't know what these things are, but you do! And through your answers and questions, we learn a little more about what makes you such a great person every day. The things like your attitude, willingness to learn, and caring for others also make you a good user.

So don't judge yourself based on reputation- we all know that there is more to it than that.

Comment: "So don't judge yourself based on reputation- we all know that there is more to it than that." Like age, AMIRITE?!

Answer (score 6):

I tried writing a query for that:

```
SELECT Age, AVG(Reputation) as 'Average',MAX(Reputation) as 'Highest'
FROM Users
GROUP BY Age
ORDER BY Age
```

Link: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/180217

Looking at your age, which is 14, I got the average of 225 and the highest was 21884 (at the current time of writing). I think you are better than the average. Unfortunately, you still have to do a lot more to topple the top.

Answer (score 1):

For me the pure count of rep is mostly an indicator of how many time you spent on SO.

**It is not possible to judge your abilities in Programming/Life or something else by looking at your reputation.**

If I want to have an idea about the quality (of the answers) of an SO member for some reason, I look at the rep per answer ratio.
(So, high rep in a short amount of time with lots of answers is rather not positive to me)